# Best Stack Exchange site for API questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to integrate my software with eBay, Facebook, Twitter, etc. Where would be the best place to ask those questions (about specific API usage)?

Answer (score 9):

Try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). The APIs for Facebook, Twitter, Google Maps, eBay seem to have thriving subcommunities on SO. One way to find out is to see if [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) exist with the name of the service.

All API questions are on topic on SO, provided they don't have other issues—they may be too localized. If, as Robert Harvey mentioned below,  "*the only hope for answering them is if one of the company representatives happens to stumble over the question, it is too localized.*"

Though bug reports should go to the API providers. Also certain kinds of support questions (these become too localized as well).

Comment: Questions about API usage are generally on-topic on Stack Overflow, provided they satisfy the other criteria (a practical programming problem, etc.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What about questions regarding obscure APIs?

Comment: If the only hope for answering them is if one of the company representatives happens to stumble over the question, it is too localized.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: True. I'll edit that in.